# How to maintain user's state while page refresh in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, cookies, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm new to Nuxt, I created a project with Universal mode, I have a problem maintaining the user state when page refresh, the store and auth module get vanished on refresh, so unable to retrieve the values from the store on refresh.

I tried using a middleware to retreive the data from local stroage, but it is not possible, since the middleware runs serverside, tried to set the user details in cookies, but unable to set the cookies.

could some one suggest a best approach on maintaining the user state on page refresh.

```
userLogin() {
      try {
        this.$axios.post('api/auth/Signin', this.login).then((res) => {
          this.$auth.setToken('local', 'Bearer ' + res.data.data.token)

          this.$axios.setHeader(
            'Authorization',
            'Bearer ' + res.data.data.token
          )
          this.$auth.ctx.app.$axios.setHeader(
            'Authorization',
            'Bearer ' + res.data.data.token
          )
          this.$axios.get('api/auth/User').then((res) => {
            this.$auth.setUser(res.data.user)
            this.$cookies.set('user', res.data.user, {
              path: '/',
              maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
            })            
            this.$router.push('/')
          })
        })

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }

// middleware function 
export default function({ req, $auth, redirect, store }) {
  // redirect to login page if the user is not authenticated
  if (!$auth.isloggedIn) {
    if (!process.client) {
      const cookie = require('cookie')
      const cookies = req.headers.cookie
      const parsedCookies = cookie.parse(cookies)
      const token = parsedCookies['auth._token.local']
      const user = parsedCookies.user

      if (!token) return redirect('/login')
      else {
        store.dispatch('loginStatus', true)
        store.dispatch('setUser', user)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you unable to set the cookies?

Comment: Not sure, above is the code in login function i used to set the cookie, after login when i inspect the cookies section of my browser, i could only see the token and the strategy but not the user.  I'm using 'cookie-universal-nuxt' module,

Comment: I'm unable to set the cookie with the object, but i'm able to set it with boolean and strings

Comment: cookies are saved as strings, you need to stringify your object first with `JSON.stringify(object)` then you can save it

Comment: later you can get that stringifyed object and parse it back `JSON.parse()`

Comment: I'm unable to set the cookie with the response object, but i'm able to set it by creating a new object from the response

Comment: Thanks Ifaruki, I found the issue, it was due to the response object of the user is huge. after extracting the required details as a new object I was able to set the cookie.